# DRY-ing a common R code pattern

Tags: r

I've got what I imagine is a fairly common pattern in some r code. I've got a data frame with a numeric vector, and I want to create another factor variable based on particular values of the numeric vector.

Currently this is what my code looks like:

```
add_category <- function(sample) {
   sample$category <- NA
   sample$category[sample$numeric_vars < 25000] <- '1. Below 25k'
   sample$category[sample$numeric_vars >= 25000] <- '2. Above 25k'
   sample$category[sample$numeric_vars >= 50000] <- '3. Above 50k'
   sample$category <- as.factor(sample$category)
   return(sample)
}
```

The problem that I have is that this code has a bunch of repetition and I can't test it easily. I've been trying to work out a way to make it less repetitious, but I've been banging my head against it for a few hours without much success.

So my question is, how do you replicate this pattern in a DRY fashion in base R?

**EDIT:**

So just to make this a bit clearer, I'm aware that I can use `cut` to fix this particular problem. I'm more interested in strategies to solve this category of problem, the recoding of a separate variable based on some test of particular instances of another variable.

In Hadley's advanced R's functional programming section he uses the example of recoding -99 as `NA` across a number of columns. This is similar but for a variety of values on one column.

Comment: You could reduce the number of code lines with `cut`. i.e.  `cut(sample$numeric_vars, breaks=c(-Inf, 25000, 50000,Inf), labels=yourlabels)`  An example data would be helpful

Comment: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#fp-motivation

Comment: @Khashaa yes, that chapter was useful, but in it Hadley is talking about applying a similar operation across a variety of columns, this is on the one column with a variety of values.

Comment: Another option is `factor(1+ 2*(v1 < 25000) + 4*(v1 >= 25000) + 8*(v1 >= 50000), labels=c('1. Below 25k', '2. Above 25k', '3. Above 50k'))` where `v1` is the vector of values.

Comment: If you are asking for a general principle, I would say your question is a little too broad,  and I think Hadley addresses it eloquently in his book.

Answer (score 1):

I can shave a couple of lines off. Otherwise it looks fine.

```
add_category <- function(sample) {
    sample$category <- '1. Below 25k'
    sample$category[sample$numeric_vars >= 25000] <- '2. Above 25k'
    sample$category[sample$numeric_vars >= 50000] <- '3. Above 50k'
    return(sample)
}
```

It should already be as factors.

Answer (score 1):

With only a few levels, as in this case, it's still reasonable to do it manually.

```
df <- data.frame(numeric.var = runif(100000,0,75000))
add_Cat <- function(var) {
  as.factor(ifelse(var > 50000, "3. Above 50k",
    ifelse(var > 25000, "2. Above 25k", "1. Below 25k'")))
}
```

I have a more general solution if you are interested, but it mauls KISS in order to get DRY.

Actually I retract this answer and need to rethink my code elsewhere after running the following benchmark:

```
microbenchmark(add_Cat(df), add_category(df))
Unit: microseconds
            expr       min         lq       mean    median         uq        max neval
     add_Cat(df) 69179.970 70801.9170 72700.5511 71881.748 72627.1110 144267.491   100
add_category(df)   690.199   728.6855   894.3915   778.535   803.2765   2717.907   100
```

Comment: Sure, let's see the complicated version!